# How can I label a partition on linux

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, storage

I'm new to linux and I want to set up my partition. I have ssd and hdd
my partition is like this

1:
fat32 /boot/efi 512MB
ext4 / 30GB
ext4 /home (rest of the storage)

2: (for the harddisk)
ext4 /games(the whole harddisk)

So the question is: can I name(label) my harddisk partition on linux?

Comment: so the question is can I labeled my partition sorry I didn't ask it I'm new and I'm stupid

Comment: As it is written this question does not have even the littlest bit of sense.

Comment: sorry lol I'm stupid so can I name(label) my harddisk partition on linux?

Comment: If you think you can make the question make some sense edit it not add comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can label a partition. Use "Disks" utility for that.

Comment: Thanks man for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Gaparted, It's easy to use. If you don't have Gparted installed, install it by

***`sudo apt install gparted`***

Comment: Thanks for answering my question!

Comment: It may be useful to mention how to use GParted to answer the question.